# Programmatically set src attribute for JavaScript link on masterpage?

Tags: javascript, master-page

The dev site was set up as a subsite in a site collection with the URL `http://server/sites/site` but on the production server it's just `http://site` so the src attribute on the dev box `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Sites/site/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>` obviously doesn't work on the prod box. I tried to set it like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" %></script>
```

but no luck (tried with/without runat="server"). What's the preferred approach here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not copy it to a mapped folder in the 14 hive, like `/_layouts/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js` that way it is accessible from any site/web?

Should do the trick.